# How to create vector of variate_generator?

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create a vector of boost random number generators.

I've tried creating function pointers to the variate_generators without much luck either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    const double mean = 0.0;
    const double sigma = 1.0;

    // Setup aliases
    typedef boost::normal_distribution<> NormalDistribution;
    typedef boost::mt19937 RandomNumberGenerator;
    typedef boost::variate_generator<RandomNumberGenerator&, NormalDistribution> NormalGenerator;

    vector<NormalGenerator> gen_vec;

    RandomNumberGenerator rng;
    rng.seed(12345);

    NormalDistribution noise_distribution(mean, sigma);

    NormalGenerator rng_eng(rng, noise_distribution); // create RNG

    gen_vec.push_back(rng_eng);

    return 0;
}
```

I was hoping to use gen_vec to get a function in order to generate a random number for a given element in the vector. But when I attempt to compile it throws this error.

```
/usr/include/boost/random/detail/pass_through_engine.hpp:27: error: non-static reference member \u2018main(int, const char**)::RandomNumberGenerator& boost::random::detail::pass_through_engine<main(int, const char**)::RandomNumberGenerator&>::_rng\u2019, can't use default assignment operator
```

I'm guessing that's because I'm not packing the variate_generators correctly.

Is what I'm trying to do correct much less possible?

Comment: why do you want a vector of random generators? Either you use the same seed then they all will give you the same sequence, if you dont you get random numbers just as you would from using a single generator

Comment: I'll have multiple distributions and I currently get those distributions through another vector. I figured this would be a convenient way to generate random generators given that.

Comment: I have a similar situation only that in my case the number of random vars is case dependent and parameters are chosen by the user.  So in each instance one may have a different number of distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, your example code does compile without any error message (GCC 8.2.1, boost 1.69).

But, don't do that. Just use boost::variate_generator<>::distribution() to set a new distribution.

```cpp
NormalDistribution noise_distribution(mean, sigma);
NormalDistribution other_distribution(5.0, 2.0);
NormalGenerator rng_eng(rng, noise_distribution); // create RNG
// ... generate RNG using noise_distribution
rng_eng.distribution() = other_distribution;
// ... generate RNG using other_distribution
rng_eng.distribution() = noise_distribution;
// ... generate RNG using noise_distribution again
```